# Android activity for User option in Jelly Bean?

Tags: android-activity, android-4.2-jelly-bean

Could someone tell me what is the activity of User option in Android 4.2 tablet? 
I want to start this intent by "adb shell am" command but i don't know that activity. Does it exist or not?

Answer (score 0):

After direct check I confirm **am** is available on my Google Galaxy Nexus, Android 4.1.2. This is quite close to 4.2.

`adb shell am` prints the two screens of the built-in documentation that may help.

Comment: Maybe you're misunderstanding, i would like to know the activity of User option in Settings. This option is only available in tablet, and disable in mobile. 
I run "adb shell logcat" to get the activity but all the option (Display, Sound, Storage,..) return the same "com.android.settings/.SubSettings" activity.